# WCF service server throws an exception Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, wcf, events, service, delegates

So my service is a simple chat application between two wcf clients. Event callback works when I call events. After I close my client and run it again, and write a message again (to call the event) it throws me exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in
RussianRouletteServiceLibrary.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot access a disposed object.
```

The code for my service callback is as follows:

```
    private static Action<User, UMessage> gameChat = delegate { };

    public void Play()
    {
        IGameCallback subscriber =
                   OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IGameCallback>();
        gameChat += subscriber.PlayerSentMessage;
    }
```

This is the event trigger:

```
    public void SendMessage(User user, UMessage message)
    {
        try
        {
            gameChat(user, message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I get this error every time I `.ChannelFactory.Close();` `.Close();` the client while closing form event is happening.

Is there anyone that knows how to fix this and is willing to share his knowledge?
Thank you in advance!

EDIT #1
This is the code of the client when it opens:

```
    ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
    UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
    public partial class GameForm : Form, IGameCallback
    {
    #region IGame Callbacks
    public void PlayerSentMessage(User user, UMessage message)
    {
        string nickname = user.NickName == clientUser.NickName ? "You" : user.NickName;
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => lb_ChatBox.Items.Add(nickname + " : " + message.MessageContent)));
     }
    #endregion

    private GameClient _gameClient = null;
    private InstanceContext _instance = null;
    private User clientUser = new User(){ Email = "zigm4s@gmail.com", Id = 0, FirstName = "Zigmas", LastName = "Slusnys", NickName = "Ziggy", Password = "test123"};




    public GameForm()
    {
        string state;


        if (_gameClient != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("nelygu null");
            MessageBox.Show(_gameClient.State.ToString());
            //_gameClient = new GameClient(new InstanceContext(this));
        }
        else
        {

            _gameClient = new GameClient(new InstanceContext(this));
            MessageBox.Show(_gameClient.State.ToString());
        }

        InitializeComponent();

        try
        {
            _gameClient.Open();
            _gameClient.Play();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

This is when the client form is closing.

```
    private void GameForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            if (_gameClient.State != System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Faulted)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Closing client");
                _gameClient.ChannelFactory.Close();
                _gameClient.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Aborting client");
                _gameClient.Abort();
            }
            }
        catch(Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());}
    }
```

EDIT #2
I found the mistake, on the service side i had delegates that were static. It doesn't throw this error when it's not static.

Comment: Can you show more code on how you close the client and then create a new one?

Comment: I added the client opening and closing, you think somethings wrong with how I close the client?